# ASP.NET MVC: How to handle model data that must go to every view?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, models, global

So if there is some global state that every view of an MVC app will need to render ... for example: `IsUserLoggedOn` and `UserName` ... whats the appropriate way of getting that information to every view?

I understand that that part of the view should be in the master page or in a partial view thats added to the other views. But whats a good way to make sure the 'global' model data is passed to the view every time from all the relevant controllers and actions?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

After asking this, I found this good blog post by Steve Sanderson:
http://blog.stevensanderson.com/2008/10/14/partial-requests-in-aspnet-mvc/

He suggests three different approaches:

- Use a base controller class or ActionFilter to add the relevant model to the `ViewData[]` collection every time. I think a few people have suggested that sort of thing already.
- Use `Html.RenderAction()` in the view ... and as he says:

> If someone tells you that internal
>   subrequests are bad because
>   it “isn’t MVC”, then just bite them on
>   the face immediately. Also ask them
>   why they’re still willing to use Ajax,
>   and even `<IMG>` tags for that matter,
>   given that both are a form of
>   subrequest.

- Use 'Partial Requests' (he provides the code for this on [his blog](http://blog.stevensanderson.com/2008/10/14/partial-requests-in-aspnet-mvc/)) which allow one controller to nest calls to other controllers into a sortof nested `ViewData` structure.

Answer (score 3):

codeulike - see the answer to a similar question asked at exactly the same time as this:

[ASP.NET MVC displaying user name from a Profile](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4036582/asp-net-mvc-displaying-user-name-from-a-profile)

in a nutshell, basically create a base controller that's inherited by all your other controllers. the base controller then has an override function that carries thro' to all 'child' controllers. rather than duplicate the code, take a look at my answer above and give it a try..

cheers...

Answer (score 2):

You could create base class for viewmodel which contains shared information and inherit that for each viewmodel.

```
public class ViewModelBase
{
    // shared data
}
public class Page1ViewModel : ViewModelBase
{
    // page 1 data
}
```

In masterpage you could use that base class

```
Inherits="System.Web.Mvc.ViewMasterPage<ViewModelBase>"
```

and in each view use those derived classes

```
Inherits="System.Web.Mvc.ViewPage<Page1ViewModel>"
```

Comment: Right, but how do I populate that viewmodel every time? Presumably with a base controller, right?

Comment: ViewModelBase constructor/helper class/controller base class