# ASP.NET MVC displaying user name from a Profile

Tags: asp.net-mvc, user-controls, master-pages

The following is the **LogOn** user control from a standard default ASP.NET MVC project created by Visual Studio (**LogOnUserControl.ascx**):

```
<%@ Control Language="C#" Inherits="System.Web.Mvc.ViewUserControl" %>
<%
if (Request.IsAuthenticated) {
%>
Welcome <b><%: Page.User.Identity.Name %></b>!
[ <%: Html.ActionLink("Log Off", "LogOff", "Account") %> ]
<%
}
else {
%> 
[ <%: Html.ActionLink("Log On", "LogOn", "Account")%> ]
<%
}
%>
```

which is inserted into a master page:

```
<div id="logindisplay">
    <% Html.RenderPartial("LogOnUserControl"); %>
</div>
```

The `<%: Page.User.Identity.Name %>` code displays the **login name** of the user, currently logged in.

**How to display the user's `FirstName` instead, which is saved in the Profile?**

We can read it in a controller like following:

```
ViewData["FirstName"] = AccountProfile.CurrentUser.FirstName;
```

If we, for example, try to do this way:

```
<%: ViewData["FirstName"] %>
```

It renders only on the page which was called by the controller where the  `ViewData["FirstName"]` value was assigned.

Comment: See related link: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/976493/asp-net-mvc-set-viewdata-for-masterpage-in-base-controller

Answer (score 11, accepted):

rem,

this is one of those cases where having a base controller would solve 'all' your problems (well, some anyway). in your base controller, you'd have something like:

```
public abstract partial class BaseController : Controller
{
    // other stuff omitted
    protected override void OnActionExecuted(ActionExecutedContext filterContext)
    {
        ViewData["FirstName"] = AccountProfile.CurrentUser.FirstName;
        base.OnActionExecuted(filterContext);
    }
}
```

and use it in all your controllers like:

```
public partial class MyController : BaseController
{
    // usual stuff
}
```

or similar. you'd then always have it available to every action across all controllers.

see if it works for you.

Comment: Thanks, jim! Very useful. +1. But how, in this case, I could make sure that ViewData is assigned "AccountProfile.CurrentUser.FirstName"  value at the moment of user logged in (right after this moment)?

Comment: rem - as long as this AccountProfile is available via some 'mechanism', it'll be available in the override that i txtd above. i know this for a fact as i do this in exactly the same way for a custom profile on an app that i'm working on right now today!! in fact, just try it :)

Comment: @jimtollan- I like your answer. I just want to know what is that AccountProfile represents? Because I'm also wants to implement it on my system but get a red mark on it.. thanks.. ;)

Comment: hi bot. `AccountProfile.CurrentUser.FirstName` is a custom profile object that ihad in my code at that point in time. for your purposes, i gues you might use `User.Identity.Name`